# Can I enter the Schengen Area using a C/ZA Romanian Visa?

Tags: schengen, romania

Is it possible to enter the Schengen Area using the [C/ZA visa](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2046?page=2) (Cultural, scientific and humanitarian activities visa) issued by Romania?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Romania participates only partially in the Schengen construction -- in particular, it cannot yet issue visas that will be valid for the full Schengen member states.

Answer (score 0):

> Schengen area member: : No, Romania is **not a member** of the
>   Schengen Area.

https://europa.eu/european-union/about-eu/countries/member-countries/romania_en